# Plotting ROC curve - too many indices error

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, roc

I'm picking up the ROC code straight from here: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/plot_roc.html

I've hard coded my number of classes as 46, in the for loop, as you can see, however even if I set it down to as low as 2, I still get an error.

```
# Compute ROC curve and ROC area for each class
tpr = dict()
roc_auc = dict()
for i in range(46):
    fpr[i], tpr[i], _ = roc_curve(y_test[:, i], y_pred[:, i])
    roc_auc[i] = auc(fpr[i], tpr[i])
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\app\Documents\Python Scripts\gbc_classifier_test.py", line 150, in <module>
    fpr[i], tpr[i], _ = roc_curve(y_test[:, i], y_pred[:, i])
IndexError: too many indices
```

`y_pred` is as you can see here:
[array.shape() giving error tuple not callable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25125168/array-shape-giving-error-tuple-not-callable/25125173#25125173)

and `y_test` is just a 1D array similar to y_pred, except with the true classes of my problem.

I don't understand, what has too many indices?

Answer (score 5):

Both the `y_pred` shown in your other question and `y_test` are 1-d, so the expressions `y_pred[:, i]` and `y_test[:, i]` have too many indices. You can only index a 1-d array with a single index.

That said, you should probably just call `roc_curve(y_test, y_pred)`.