# IndexError: too many indices for array while plotting ROC curve with scikit-learn?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scikit-learn

I would like to plott the ROC curve that scikit-lern implements so I tried the following:

```
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, auc
false_positive_rate, recall, thresholds = roc_curve(y_test, prediction[:, 1])
roc_auc = auc(false_positive_rate, recall)
plt.title('Receiver Operating Characteristic')
plt.plot(false_positive_rate, recall, 'b', label='AUC = %0.2f' % roc_auc)
plt.legend(loc='lower right')
plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], 'r--')
plt.xlim([0.0, 1.0])
plt.ylim([0.0, 1.0])
plt.ylabel('Recall')
plt.xlabel('Fall-out')
plt.show()
```

And this is the output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/script.py", line 62, in <module>
    false_positive_rate, recall, thresholds = roc_curve(y_test, prediction[:, 1])
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

Then from a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25125300/plotting-roc-curve-too-many-indices-error) I tried this:

```
false_positive_rate, recall, thresholds = roc_curve(y_test, prediction)
```

And got this traceback:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/metrics.py:705: DeprecationWarning: elementwise comparison failed; this will raise the error in the future.
  not (np.all(classes == [0, 1]) or
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/metrics.py:706: DeprecationWarning: elementwise comparison failed; this will raise the error in the future.
  np.all(classes == [-1, 1]) or
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/TESIS_CODE/clasificacion_simple_v1.py", line 62, in <module>
    false_positive_rate, recall, thresholds = roc_curve(y_test, prediction)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/metrics.py", line 890, in roc_curve
    y_true, y_score, pos_label=pos_label, sample_weight=sample_weight)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/metrics.py", line 710, in _binary_clf_curve
    raise ValueError("Data is not binary and pos_label is not specified")
ValueError: Data is not binary and pos_label is not specified
```

Then I also tried this:

```
false_positive_rate, recall, thresholds = roc_curve(y_test, prediction[0].values)
```

And this is the traceback:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.int64' object has no attribute 'values'
```

Any idea of how to correctly plot this metric?. Thanks in advance!

This is the shape of the prediction varibale:

```
print prediction.shape
(650,)
```

this is the shape of `testing_matrix: (650, 9596)`

Comment: Can you check the `type` of the prediction variable and update the question to show how it is created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `prediction` needs to be a `1d array` (the same shape as  `y_test`). You can check by inspecting the shape attribute e.g. `y_test.shape`. I think

```
prediction[0].values
```

returns

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.int64' object has no attribute 'values'
```

because you are trying to call `.values` on an element of prediction.

**Update:**

```
ValueError: Data is not binary and pos_label is not specified
```

I didn't notice this before. If your classes are not binary, you have to specify the `pos_label` parameter when in`roc_curve` so it plots one class vs the rest. For this to work you need your class labels to be integers. You can use:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
class_labels = LabelEncoder()
prediction_le = class_lables.fit_transform(prediction)
```

`pediction_le` returns classes recodes a `int`

**Update 2:**

Your predictor is only returning one class, so you cannot plot the ROC curve

Comment: Thanks for the help @JAB, this is the shape of the attibute: `(650,)`. I updated.

Comment: sorry couldn't see for looking- what does `.shape` produce for `y_test`?

Comment: also what are the distinct values from prediction?

Comment: for `y_test: (650,)` and for prediction:`[ 2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.
  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.
  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.
....  2.  2.]` It drops a large .2 matrix, thanks

Comment: this is the output: `set([2.0])`

Comment: You need at least two predicted classes to plot the roc_curve

Comment: 'How do I optimize my model' is a different question and more suited to cross validated. My answer addresses your original question. Please accept it if you agree.

Comment: I see so this is an optimization issue... sorry but I did not understood, thanks for the help. So there is no way to plot the ROC given this data/code?

Comment: I think the code is ok. What is the shape of  `testing_matrix`? Is `m` larger than `n`?

Comment: No, this is the shape of testing_matrix: (650, 9596)